# How to loop through pack_rows in r using kableextra package?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex, kableextra

```
A   C
-------
KK  1
KK  3
KK  3
AA  4
AA  52
BB  33
BB  7
BB  83
DD  91
DD  10
```

i have a table like the  one above i want to use column A and make it into groups
and use start and end index to be used in pack_rows to automate using the dataframe above.
i tried to use for loop but it didn't work it showing error in loop so how can i loop through
using below code

```
kbl(df,booktabs = T,longtable = T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"),bootstrap_options = "bordered",font_size = 7,full_width = F)%>%
  row_spec(0, bold = T, color = "white", background = "#008752")%>% 
  pack_rows("KK", 1, 3,background = "#008000")%>%
  pack_rows("AA", 4, 5,background = "#008000")
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `A` column as factor with levels same as appearance. Use `table` in `pack_rows` -

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df$A <- factor(df$A, unique(df$A))

kbl(df,booktabs = T,longtable = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"),
        bootstrap_options = "bordered",font_size = 7,full_width = F)%>%
  row_spec(0, bold = T, color = "white", background = "#008752")%>% 
  pack_rows(index = table(df$A), background = "#008000")
```

[image]